# Summing subsequent list entries

Tags: python, loops, sum

I am a beginner with python and I want to add each entry of a list (of days in a month) to the previous entry to get a sum of total days in a year.

a is a list of days in each month

```
a = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

I want b to be a list of totals like this:

```
b= (a[0],a[0]+a[1],a[0]+a[1]+a[2],a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3],a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+a[4]...
```

I don't know how to make a loop to do this.
Help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You should first learn about loops. Then use that to sum up elements in a list. It's simple, really. Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website.

Comment: [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: `[sum(L[:i] for i in range(1, len(L)+1)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
b = [sum(a[:i]) for i in range(1, len(a) + 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for that!